# ghcjs-jquery is incompatible with base-4.8.0.0, what to do?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, ghcjs

ghcjs-jquery is not compatible with base-4.8.0.0, what can one do ?

**details**:

```
joco@vm001:~/Downloads$ git clone https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-jquery.git
Cloning into 'ghcjs-jquery'...
remote: Counting objects: 142, done.
remote: Total 142 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 142
Receiving objects: 100% (142/142), 110.25 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (59/59), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
joco@vm001:~/Downloads$ ls
Cabal-1.22.3.0          cabal-install-1.22.3.0.tar.gz                 ghcjs            ghcjs-jquery  node-v0.12.4.tar.gz
Cabal-1.22.3.0.tar.gz   ghc-7.10.1                                    ghcjs-dom-hello  ghcjs-prim    regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.3
cabal-install-1.22.3.0  ghc-7.10.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.bz2  ghcjs-examples   node-v0.12.4  regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.3.tar.gz
joco@vm001:~/Downloads$ cd ghcjs-jquery/
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ ls
example  ghcjs-jquery.cabal  JavaScript  jquery  jsbits  LICENSE  README.md  Setup.hs  util
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ cabal install --ghcjs
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: ghcjs-jquery-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of ghcjs-jquery-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0/installed-55a... (conflict: ghcjs-jquery =>
base==4.7.*)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0,
4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0,
4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed
instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ cabal sandbox init
Writing a default package environment file to
/home/joco/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery/cabal.sandbox.config
Creating a new sandbox at /home/joco/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery/.cabal-sandbox
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ cabal install --ghcjs
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: ghcjs-jquery-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of ghcjs-jquery-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0/installed-55a... (conflict: ghcjs-jquery =>
base==4.7.*)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0,
4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0,
4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed
instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ ls
cabal.sandbox.config  example  ghcjs-jquery.cabal  JavaScript  jquery  jsbits  LICENSE  README.md  Setup.hs  util
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ vi ghcjs-jquery.cabal 
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ cabal install base-4.7.0.2
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: base (user goal)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0/installed-1b6..., 4.8.0.0 (global constraint requires
==4.7.0.2)
rejecting: base-4.7.0.2 (only already installed instances can be used)
rejecting: base-4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0,
4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0,
3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires ==4.7.0.2)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ cabal sandbox init
Writing a default package environment file to
/home/joco/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery/cabal.sandbox.config
Creating a new sandbox at /home/joco/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery/.cabal-sandbox
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ cabal install base-4.7.0.2
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: base (user goal)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0/installed-1b6..., 4.8.0.0 (global constraint requires
==4.7.0.2)
rejecting: base-4.7.0.2 (only already installed instances can be used)
rejecting: base-4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0,
4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0,
3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires ==4.7.0.2)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.

joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$ ghcjs --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System for JavaScript, version 0.1.0 (GHC 7.10.1)
joco@vm001:~/Downloads/ghcjs-jquery$
```

Comment: Upper bounds on base :( Try passing `--allow-newer=base` to `cabal install`.

Comment: Thanks, I try. Is there a way to get base-4.7.0.2 ? An older GHC perhaps?

Comment: Yes, base-4.7.* is GHC 7.8.*.

Comment: Base comes prepackaged with GHC so for 4.7.0.2 you will need GHC 7.8.*

Comment: `--allow-newer=base` seems to help, at least it compiles

Comment: @ReidBarton since that provided the answer, you should post it as an answer.